# [HTML][CSS] Display div on hover, targeted

Tags: css, html

When displaying a div on hover, how can you target a specific div? 
I need to display a hidden div from a link is on top of the page, and I can't figure out how.
When i tested, if the link and the div are one after the other, it displays corectly. but if i add another link before the first one, it does not work anymore.
From my testing using this CSS:

```
.expandable{
display: none;
}
.expand:hover+.expandable{
display:inline !important;
}
.expandable:hover{
display:inline !important;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<div class="expand">expand</div> <!--this does not do anithing-->
<div class="expand">expand</div> <!--this works-->
<div class="expandable">expandable</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below one

```
.expandable{
display: none;
}
.expand:hover ~.expandable{
display:inline !important;
}
.expandable:hover{
display:inline !important;
}
```

Comment: Might want to add that `+` is the adjacent sibling selector while `~` is the general sibling selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators

Comment: This is the answer i was looking for, hard one to find, thank you! The ~ does the magic. I can use jQuery, but i was looking for a way to do it without.

Comment: I did a but of research on the "~" and the sequencees need to share the same parent o the document tree. The example i gave is a simplified version of the core i have. The initial code puts both sequences in other <div> contructs. :( so i need to search  a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Only the hover on the second div works because of the behaviour of the '+' selector

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp

What W3C says :

Select and style every p element that are placed **immediately after** div elements:

```
div + p { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can hide div by id using : jQuery :

```
<div id=“div”>

</div>

<script>
$(“#div”).hide("slow"); // you can change "hide" to "show" 
</script>
```